# convert english number with farsi or arabic number in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new in `Dart` and `flutter`.

I want to replace English number with Farsi number.
How can implement this?

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9 ==> ‍‍۱-۲-۳-۴-۵-۶-۷-۸-۹
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Example:

```dart
String replaceFarsiNumber(String input) {
  const english = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
  const farsi = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];

  for (int i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
    input = input.replaceAll(english[i], farsi[i]);
  }

  return input;
}

main() {
  print(replaceFarsiNumber('0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9'));  // ==>  ۰-۱-۲-۳-۴-۵-۶-۷-۸-۹
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure in what context you're going to use the numbers, but I would rather define a const map:
`const numberMap = {0: '۰', 1: '۱', 2:'۲', 3:'۳', 4:'٤', 5:'۵', 6:'٦', 7:'۷', 8:'۸',9: '۹'};`
Then you can just call `numberMap[number]` to reuse it.

Comment: I think `Map` must be defined with `{}` instead `[]`

Comment: ah sorry my bad. Edited.

Answer (score 4):

```
static String ConvertDigitsToLatin(String s) {
var sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  switch (s[i]) {
    //Persian digits
    case '\u06f0':
      sb.write('0');
      break;
    case '\u06f1':
      sb.write('1');
      break;
    case '\u06f2':
      sb.write('2');
      break;
    case '\u06f3':
      sb.write('3');
      break;
    case '\u06f4':
      sb.write('4');
      break;
    case '\u06f5':
      sb.write('5');
      break;
    case '\u06f6':
      sb.write('6');
      break;
    case '\u06f7':
      sb.write('7');
      break;
    case '\u06f8':
      sb.write('8');
      break;
    case '\u06f9':
      sb.write('9');
      break;

    //Arabic digits
    case '\u0660':
      sb.write('0');
      break;
    case '\u0661':
      sb.write('1');
      break;
    case '\u0662':
      sb.write('2');
      break;
    case '\u0663':
      sb.write('3');
      break;
    case '\u0664':
      sb.write('4');
      break;
    case '\u0665':
      sb.write('5');
      break;
    case '\u0666':
      sb.write('6');
      break;
    case '\u0667':
      sb.write('7');
      break;
    case '\u0668':
      sb.write('8');
      break;
    case '\u0669':
      sb.write('9');
      break;
    default:
      sb.write(s[i]);
      break;
  }
}
return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Worked with me!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63934087/14409491

```
extension NumberConverter on num {
  static const Map<String, String> arabicDigits = <String, String>{
    '0': '\u0660',
    '1': '\u0661',
    '2': '\u0662',
    '3': '\u0663',
    '4': '\u0664',
    '5': '\u0665',
    '6': '\u0666',
    '7': '\u0667',
    '8': '\u0668',
    '9': '\u0669',
  };

  String toArabicDigits() {
    final String number = toString();
    StringBuffer sb = StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
      sb.write(arabicDigits[number[i]] ?? number[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
String engNumberToFarsi(String number) {

    Map numbers = {
        '0' : '۰',
        '1' : '۱',
        '2' : '۲',
        '3' : '۳',
        '4' : '۴',
        '5' : '۵',
        '6' : '۶',
        '7' : '۷',
        '8' : '۸',
        '9' : '۹',
    };

    numbers.forEach((key, value) => number = number.replaceAll(key, value));

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party but here is a solution using `RegExp` and `String.replaceAllMapped(...)`:

```dart
extension ToFarsiNumber on String {
  String toFarsi() {
    const Map<String, String> numbers = {
      '0': '۰',
      '1': '۱',
      '2': '۲',
      '3': '۳',
      '4': '۴',
      '5': '۵',
      '6': '۶',
      '7': '۷',
      '8': '۸',
      '9': '۹',
    };

    return replaceAllMapped(
      RegExp('[0-9]'),
      (match) => numbers[this[match.start]]!,
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
'0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9'.toFarsi(); // ۰-۱-۲-۳-۴-۵-۶-۷-۸-۹
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import 'package:alert_dialog/alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home2> createState() => _Home2State();
}

class _Home2State extends State<Home2> {
  String TransformerNum = 'محمود 2026';
  TextEditingController TransformerNumController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('ArbicNumbers'),),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:220,left: 650),
              child: Text('${TransformerNum}',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: '(A) Arslan Wessam A', fontSize: 25)),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:220,left: 650),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text('${TransformerNum}',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: '(A) Arslan Wessam A', fontSize: 25)),
                    SizedBox(width: 10,),
                    Text('اضف بيانات المحول ',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: '(A) Arslan Wessam A', fontSize: 25)),

                  ],
                ),
                onPressed: () async{
                  return alert(
                      context,
                      title: Column(
                        children: [

                          Container(
// margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:200, top: 200, right: 300),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                controller: TransformerNumController,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'ادخل البيانات',
                                    hintMaxLines: 1,
                                    enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                        )),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200)),
                                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                      Icons.add_circle_outline_outlined,
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                    ),
                                    fillColor: Colors.lightBlue[50],
                                    filled: true,
                                    hintText: '....... مثال 1او 2 او'),

                              )
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),

                      textOK: IconButton(onPressed: (){
                        setState((){
                          TransformerNum = replaceFarsiNumber(TransformerNumController.text);
                          //TransformerNum = TransformerNumController.text;
                        });
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }, icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle))
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  String replaceFarsiNumber(String input) {
    const english = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    const farsi = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '٦', '۷', '۸', '۹'];

    for (int i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
      input = input.replaceAll(english[i], farsi[i]);
    }

    return input;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works on Windows

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

@Xavier answer is correct, however I would suggest to define an extension to use instead of each time wrapping your string with function

```
extension FarsiNumberExtension on String {
  String get farsiNumber {
    const english = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    const farsi = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
    String text = this;
    for (int i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
      text = text.replaceAll(english[i], farsi[i]);
    }
    return text;
  }
}
```

and use like this

```
print('0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9'.farsiNumber);
print('myNumber123'.farsiNumber);
```

output

```
۰-۱-۲-۳-۴-۵-۶-۷-۸-۹
myNumber۱۲۳
```

Answer (score 0):

I have published the [`localizeDigits()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/hrk_batteries/latest/hrk_batteries/HrkString/localizeDigits.html) extension method on String in the package [`hrk_batteries`](https://pub.dev/packages/hrk_batteries).

Add the package:

```
$ dart pub add hrk_batteries
```

Use it as follows:

[localized_digits_example.dart](https://github.com/hrishikesh-kadam/hrk_batteries.dart/blob/main/example/localized_digits_example.dart)

```dart
import 'package:hrk_batteries/hrk_batteries.dart';

void main() {
  final String enToArLocalizedString = 'A0123456789Z'.localizeDigits(
    toZeroDigit: '\u0660', // toZeroDigit: '٠',
  );
  print(enToArLocalizedString); // A٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩Z

  final String enToFaLocalizedString = 'A0123456789Z'.localizeDigits(
    toZeroDigit: '\u06f0', // toZeroDigit: '۰',
  );
  print(enToFaLocalizedString); // A۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹Z
}
```