# Localize digits in the String from one language to another in Dart or Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Convert en (English) digits to mr (Marathi) digits:
Input: `A0123456789Z`
Output: `A०१२३४५६७८९Z`

Convert mr (Marathi) digits to kn (Kannada) digits:
Input: `A०१२३४५६७८९Z`
Output: `A೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯Z`

Solutions to localize digits in the String from one language to another in Dart or Flutter.

### Notes on possible duplicates

This question may appear to duplicate the following questions, but it incorporates all the questions under one.

- [how to convert numbers from one language to english or forcing the user to write in english only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64051680/3302026)
- [Show Numbers In Arabic Format Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52857534/3302026)
- [convert english number with farsi or arabic number in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53394135/3302026)
- [How can I convert english numbers into another language numbers (I am using Bengali language) in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58455157/3302026)

Answer (score 0):

I have published the [`localizeDigits()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/hrk_batteries/latest/hrk_batteries/HrkString/localizeDigits.html) extension method on String in the package [`hrk_batteries`](https://pub.dev/packages/hrk_batteries).

Add the package:

```
$ dart pub add hrk_batteries
```

Use it as follows:

[localized_digits_example.dart](https://github.com/hrishikesh-kadam/hrk_batteries.dart/blob/main/example/localized_digits_example.dart)

```dart
import 'package:hrk_batteries/hrk_batteries.dart';

void main() {
  final String enToMrLocalizedString = 'A0123456789Z'.localizeDigits(
    toZeroDigit: '\u0966', // toZeroDigit: '०',
  );
  print(enToMrLocalizedString); // A०१२३४५६७८९Z

  final String mrToKnLocalizedString = 'A०१२३४५६७८९Z'.localizeDigits(
    fromZeroDigit: '\u0966', // fromZeroDigit: '०',
    toZeroDigit: '\u0ce6', // toZeroDigit: '೦',
  );
  print(mrToKnLocalizedString); // A೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯Z
}
```